# Extract function Google Sheets: Extract string of text from unwanted characters

Tags: string, function, text, extract

0-35000-99661-9.

| UPC               |     UPC     |
|    ---            |035000993619 |
|    ---            |035000993618 |
| 0-35000-99675-6   | Cell 4      |

Real question is, how would I extract the only the numbers and leave the hyphens?

How would I extract the only the numbers and leave the hyphens?